# VBA - Access database table collection

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a sub which creates a new collection of Access database object linked `tabledef`. The sub works 1/2 the time without error if code is not reset (just hitting F5), but always works if first reset. However when calling this sub in another module it only works 1/2 of the time again. Any ideas why this only works only 1/2 the time when called in another sub?

```vb
Public Tables As New Collection
Sub SET_VAR()
'##############################################################
'# 1. CREATE PUBLIC COLLECTION OF LINKED TABLES IN DB
'##############################################################
On Error GoTo handlr:
   Dim tdf As TableDef
   Dim db As Database
   Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
   For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
      If Left(tdf.Connect, 5) = "ODBC;" Then
         Tables.Add tdf, Chr(34) & tdf.Name & Chr(34)
      End If
   Next tdf
   MsgBox "Success. Linked tables public collection created!"
   Exit Sub
handlr:
   MsgBox "Error. Linked tables not added to public collection!"
   End
End Sub
```

[image]

This is the error Access gives me:

> "457 This key is already associated with an element of this
>   collection"

Comment: "457      This key is already associated with an element of this collection" I got this!

Comment: @HansUp That worked! Changing the Dim Tables and Set Tables = New Collection works %100. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first line to `Public Tables As Collection` Then, in `SET_VAR()`, add `Set Tables = New Collection`

```vb
Public Tables As Collection
Sub SET_VAR()
On Error GoTo handlr:
   Dim tdf As TableDef
   Dim db As Database
   Set Tables = New Collection
   Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
   For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
      If Left(tdf.Connect, 5) = "ODBC;" Then
         Tables.Add tdf, Chr(34) & tdf.Name & Chr(34)
      End If
   Next tdf
   MsgBox "Success. Linked tables public collection created!"
   Exit Sub
handlr:
   MsgBox "Error. Linked tables not added to public collection!" & _
        vbCrLf & "(error #" & err.Number & " :" & err.Description & ")"
End Sub
```

Since you will then start with an empty `Collection` each time the procedure runs, those changes should eliminate the duplicate key problem.

I also added the error number and description to the `MsgBox` text.  If you prefer not to show those details to the users, `Debug.Print` them to the Immediate window.  When your code encounters an error, you need to understand why it happened.

Answer (score 1):

You miss a refresh:

```
Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    If Left(tdf.Connect, 5) = "ODBC;" Then
        Tables.Add tdf, Chr(34) & tdf.Name & Chr(34)
    End If
Next tdf
db.TableDefs.Refresh
```